# Getting ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded, while json is valid

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am getting following error.

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

I check my JSON on http://jsonlint.com/ and it is showing its valid. But while doing `json.loads("spiral/data/add_links_domains.json")` this, I am getting exception. Help appreciated.
My JSON:

```
{
"www.officechai.com": "syn",
"masterchefmom.blogspot.com": "syn",
"www.digitaljunkfeed.com": "syn",
"kitchenplatter.com": "syn",
"www.womensweb.in": "scatter",
"desitraveler.com": "syn",
"www.newsgram.com": "syn",
"www.nativeplanet.com": "syn",
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are basically loading the `"spiral/data/add_links_domains.json"` *string*. Instead, you meant to use [`load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load):

```
with open("spiral/data/add_links_domains.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Yo thanks! I read the documentation now! loads for directly reading python object and load for loading the file object.

Comment: Hey its again giving error , ValueError: Expecting property name: line 10 column 1 (char 279)